# Rolling sum with a conditioned window

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

So here is an example of my data

```
> d
   customer       date revenue
1:        A 2016-01-01      32
2:        A 2016-01-03      88
3:        A 2016-01-04      80
4:        A 2016-02-01      38
5:        B 2016-01-13      44
6:        B 2016-01-24      11
7:        B 2016-01-25      50
8:        B 2016-02-26      46
> dput(d)
structure(list(customer = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B"), date = structure(c(16801, 16803, 16804, 16832, 16813, 16824, 
16825, 16857), class = "Date"), revenue = c(32, 88, 80, 38, 44, 
11, 50, 46)), .Names = c("customer", "date", "revenue"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002a60788>)
```

What i want to do is, I want to create a column, let call it roll_sum_3days.
This column is the rolling sum of revenue that happen afterward. The window size is conditioned on date column. In this case, roll_sum_3days is the sum of revenue that happen afterward and must not be later than 3 days.

The expected out come would look like this

```
   customer       date revenue    roll_sum_3days
1:        A 2016-01-01      32                168
2:        A 2016-01-03      88                 80
3:        A 2016-01-04      80                 0
4:        A 2016-02-01      38                 0
5:        B 2016-01-13      44                 0
6:        B 2016-01-24      11                 96
7:        B 2016-01-25      50                 46
8:        B 2016-01-26      46                 0
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Maybe break down your sums (why 113?, why 97?...). Also how is the window size conditioned on date?

Comment: @Sotos my bad, I mistype the number. Just edited the post. So concrete example is, lets look at the first row for customer A,168 came from 88+80 because 2016-01-03 and 2016-01-04  is within 3 days after 2016-01-01 while 2016-02-01 is not

Comment: @Sotos also, my english is not anywhere near perfect so title suggestion is more than welcome :)

Comment: So if `2016-02-01 ` is NOT within 3 days then why do you add it on the previous 80?

Comment: @sotos mistake after mistake :(

Comment: The last three rolling sum values should be `50, 0, 0` as the date from the last row is not within three days of the previous two rows.

Comment: @Jaap Thank you :D

Comment: related FR: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3241

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
library(lubridate) # for the '%m+%'-function

d[, roll_sum_3d := .SD[.SD[, .(date, date2 = date %m+% days(3), revenue)]
                       , on = .(date > date, date <= date2)
                       ][, sum(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), by = date]$V1
  , by = customer][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    customer       date revenue roll_sum_3d
> 1:        A 2016-01-01      32         168
> 2:        A 2016-01-03      88          80
> 3:        A 2016-01-04      80           0
> 4:        A 2016-02-01      38           0
> 5:        B 2016-01-13      44           0
> 6:        B 2016-01-24      11          96
> 7:        B 2016-01-25      50          46
> 8:        B 2016-01-26      46           0
> ```

What this does:

- Group `d` by `customer with`by = customer`.
- Add `roll_sum_3d` by reference with `:=`.
- Calculate `roll_sum_3d` by joining `.SD` (**S**ubset of **D**ata) for each group with a date-window of that group (`.SD[, .(date, date2 = date %m+% days(3), revenue)]` with a non-equi join `on = .(date > date, date <= date2)`, summarise the revenue for each date and give that back.

An alternative based on @Arun's comment:

```
d[, roll_sum_3d := d[d[, .(customer, date, date2 = date %m+% days(3), revenue)]
                     , on = .(customer, date > date, date <= date2)
                     , sum(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), by=.EACHI]$V1][]
```

Comment: Thank you! seems like this code working as what i want. Still need some time for me to digest the code though. Cheers!

Comment: @SmileyBcc added a short explanation and updated the outcome; if you have any further question: let me know

Comment: Seems a bit convoluted .. you can use `customer` in the join together with `by=.EACHI` as follows: `d[d, on=.(customer, date > date, date <= date2), sum(revenue), by=.EACHI]$V1`. This returns the column `roll_sum_3d`. You can then simply add it to `d` by reference.

Comment: @Arun Thx, I'm still not very used to the concept of using `by = .EACHI`. At first your suggestion didn't work, but with a little adaptation it now does :-). See the update.

Comment: No worries. It needs `date2` to be added to `d` in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I guess there is another mistake in your example: observation number 8 won't add to the count of the two previous observations as it is from february. Nevermind I've got a solution if you want using `apply()` and the `POSIXct()` function

```
df <- data.frame(customer = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
       date = structure(c(16801, 16803, 16804, 16832, 16813, 16824, 
                          16825, 16857), class = "Date"), 
       revenue = c(32, 88, 80, 38, 44, 11, 50, 46))

df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date)

calc <- function(x){
   date <- as.POSIXct(unlist(x["date"]),origin = "1970-01-01")
   customer <- unlist(x["customer"])
   # There you choose what you want to sum (here conditions are between the day and 3 days later and same customer)
   # 86400 is the number of second in a day!
   output <- sum(df[df$date > date & df$date <= (date+86400*3) & df$customer==customer,"revenue"])
   return(output)
   }

df$sum <- apply(df,1,calc)
# if you want to come back with your date format.
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df
  customer       date revenue sum
1        A 2016-01-01      32 168
2        A 2016-01-03      88  80
3        A 2016-01-04      80   0
4        A 2016-02-01      38   0
5        B 2016-01-13      44   0
6        B 2016-01-24      11  50
7        B 2016-01-25      50   0
8        B 2016-02-26      46   0
```

I couldn't keep your date format as the operator `>` won't work with it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake and for your answer :)